# JFrog Artifactory shipping with vulnerable Apache Tomcat version?

Tags: tomcat, artifactory

The current release of JFrog Artifactory (7.49.8) ships with Apache Tomcat v9.0.62 embedded. The Apache Foundation lists five security vulnerabilities in 9.0.62 (See https:/tomcat.apache.org/security-9.html), including an Apache Tomcat denial of service vulnerability (CVE-2023-24998, currently under analysis).

Where can I find info on any JFrog plans to upgrade/remediate the embedded Tomcat version? Does JFrog support the independent upgrading of Apache Tomcat at end user sites to remediate the vulnerabilities, if necessary?

Latest version of Apache Tomcat 9 is 9.0.72. Can I upgrade the embedded version (if our security analysts insist)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat version is already bumped in later version of Artifactory, version [7.55.2](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Release+Notes#ArtifactoryReleaseNotes-Artifactory7.55.2Self-Hosted) is available with upgraded version(9.0.71) of tomcat. We don't recommend manual upgrade for embedded tomcat.